# Google drive file stream, unable to `ls` or `find` some directories once synced

Tags: macos, sync, google-workspace, google-drive-file-stream

I've just synched a large (~50gb?) google drive to my local OSX 10.14.5 (Mojave), using Google Drive File Stream v.32.

I am attempting to get a list of all of the files that were synced with

```
find /Volumes/GoogleDrive/My Drive/folder
```

However, this errors out for many sub-directories, with messages like 
 the following:

```
./xyz
find: ./xyz: No such file or directory
```

the same errors obtain if I try `ls -1R`.

Interestingly, if I `cd` into the directories that cause issues, and then try `find` or `ls`, it seems to work.

Any idea what is going on here? What magic is google drive file stream using such that directories can't be recursed with `find` or `ls`, but you *can* `cd` into them and then use those commands?

Note that browsing the directories in question with mac's Finder seems to work fine - the directories are all there. It seems to be the command line tools that are having trouble coping for some reason...

Possibly related:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50802125/google-drive-file-stream-on-os-x-fails-to-ls-files

Comment: I was able to work around this somewhat by using `du` - for some reason, `du` is able to go into folders that `find` or `ls` complain about.

At the same time, `du` doesn't find all files (seems to miss a few top level files at times). So to get the best list, you can combine the results from the two.
`du -a | cut -f 2 | sort -f > ~/du-out.txt;  find . | sort -f > ~/find-out.txt; cat ~/du-out.txt ~/find-out.txt | sort -u -f > ~/combined.txt`

Answer (score 0):

I tried a different approach, to delete the Google Drive Desktop /Google File Stream cache, as described here: https://remarkablemark.medium.com/how-to-clear-google-drive-cache-abf9efc6089e

After doing this, the `ls and` find` commands seemed to work. So maybe the cache was somehow corrupted. Worth a shot if you ever run into this.

Answer (score 0):

A completely different approach might be use the GoogleDrive API.  See e.g. https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/search-files

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1123161)